# Postgres SQL Select two fields by most recent date, one field must be unique

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to find which student belongs to which homeroom, as of the latest data inputted.

Starting with this dataset:

```
student homeroom    date
Alice   200         2020-02-25
Alice   100         2019-09-16
Bob     100         2019-10-20
Bob     100         2020-02-01
```

I want to only retrieve Alice's most recent homeroom and Bob's most recent homeroom:

```
student homeroom    date
Alice   200         2020-02-25
Bob     100         2020-02-01
```

The typical answer of how to find the most recent record only applies to when you're looking for **one** field's recency:

```
SELECT
     student, homeroom, MAX(date::date) AS date
   FROM
     homeroom
   GROUP BY
     student, homeroom
```

This is **not** what I want:

```
student homeroom    date
Alice   200         2020-02-25
Alice   100         2019-09-16
Bob     100         2020-02-01
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (student) hr.*
from homeroom hr
order by student, date desc;
```

`distinct on` is a very handy Postgres extension.  It returns on row for the keys in the `distinct on` list.  The row is based on the ordering criteria in the `order by`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`

```
SELECT student, homeroom, date from
(SELECT
 student, homeroom, date, row_number() over(partition by student order by homeroom, date 
desc) as rnk
FROM
 homeroom) qry WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: I believe the `order by` in your window expression should be just "date desc".
Your function will return Alice, 100, 2019-09-16 which is wrong.